# How to set vary http header in page level in coldfusion

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have built a mobile friendly application by detecting mobile users on the fly and serving a different layout in coldfusion.which is termed as **Dynamically serving different HTML on the same URL**' by google. I should change the server http header to be a " Vary HTTP header"

now, I have to setup a vary http header based on layout, If it is a mobile then I have to set Vary: User-Agent. How can set this at page level through coldfusion.

Can I achieve this through coldfusion, if not can you help me in setting up in iis.

Thanks

Comment: [cfheader](http://cfdocs.org/cfheader)

Comment: tried, <cfheader name="Vary" value="User-Agent"> but didn't worked.

Comment: _"didn't worked"_ is completely meaningless. cfheader is a commonly used tag and works fine - that is, unless headers have already been flushed, it will set the response header specified. This may or not be what you want or be interpreted as you expect, but it works.

Comment: If what you're trying to deal with is the client _sending_ the Vary request header, and have CF behave based on that you'll want [getPageContext](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/getpagecontext) function for the CF side of things. If CF itself is the client (via cfhttp) then you use [cfhttparam](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfhttpparam) to set the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setHeader()` for this:

```
<cfscript>
pc = getPageContext().getResponse();
pc.setHeader( "vary", "user-agent" );
</cfscript>
```

This functionality isn't very well documented in the official coldfusion documentation, but [this article](http://existdissolve.com/2010/10/cfscript-alternative-to-cfheader/) tells you all you need to know.